# Output different value based on VARIABLE value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

We're running a Game of Thrones sweepstake at work (no spoilers here) and I'm using Excel to automate the results. I have a list of all the characters down one side, with a column showing their current status; `A` (alive), `D` (dead) or `DW` (Dead/Wight).

Alongside that are a series of columns with everyone's guesses lined up to the character names. Each of these cells has an `A`, `D` or `DW` depending on the person's guess.

Along the bottom are the scores.

In some hidden cells below which match the layout of the above, I use the formula `=IF($B3=D3, 1, 0)` to determine if the cells match (correct guess) to add to their score.

**The tricky part** is the `DW` cell; if you guessed `DW` correctly that's `+2` to your score; if you guessed `DW` incorrectly it's `-1`.

Here's my written interpretation:

```
=IF($B3=D3, =IF(DW matches then 2, else -1, or if A or D is the same then 1), 0
```

Sample Data:

[image: Sample data here]

Comment: Whole one is bit confusing so better attach sample data along with expected results, will help us to fix the issue in better way round!!

Comment: Good idea. I've added a screenshot of the data [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky7HR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is an ideal solution, but it DID work...

`=IFS(AND($B3="DW", D3="DW"), 2, AND($B3="D", D3="DW"), -1, AND($B3="A", D3="DW"), -1, $B3=D3, 1, TRUE, 0)`